# GNSDK : Incomplete Downloads

Tags: gracenote

I'm having and have been having trouble, for over a month downloading GNSDK from https://developer.gracenote.com with the download failing and both Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox reporting network errors.

Could someone else be experiencing the same problem ? Has anyone managed to work around the problem ?